# Proper way for user to add self to newly-restored database during SQL Server Agent job?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to work with a process (SSIS project) that is supposed to restore a database file we receive from a third-party source, then draw information out of it to populate a CSV file for review.  I have been requested to use a specific service user (with permissions on the output directory) to run the SQL Server Agent job that will be doing this.  I have managed to get it to load the database, but am now running into a problem when trying to read from it.

As the third party database does not include this user, I had set up code to add the user to the database, to be run immediately after the stored procedure handling the reload.  However, in an issue which probably should have been obvious, the process cannot run that code segment as that user, erroring out with a 'login failed for user' error message.

I know that I can get around this by granting the user in question the sysadmin role, but I really don't want to do that.  What is the proper way to add this user to the database under these circumstances?

EDIT:
As per the request from Thom A in the comments, attaching additional information, name or path information obscured.

Login being used to run the job: DOMAIN\svc.an, which has been granted the 'public' and 'dbcreator' server roles.

Script used to run the DB restore:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RestoreSPDB]    Script Date: 8/29/2023 1:42:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RestoreSPDB]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @DBName nvarchar(256), --DB name to restore
    @DBRestoreFilePath nvarchar(512)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    alter database [SPDB] set single_user with rollback immediate

    RESTORE DATABASE [SPDB] FROM  DISK = @DBRestoreFilePath WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Template_Data_Data' TO N'Path\to\DB.mdf',  MOVE N'Template_Data_Log' TO N'Path\to\DB..ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5

    alter database [SPDB] set MULTI_USER    
    
END
GO
```

Immediate next task, which is failing with the error noted above:

```
USE [SPDB]
CREATE USER [domain\svc.an] FOR LOGIN [domain\svc.an]
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [domain\svc.an]
GO
```

If any more information is needed, please let me know what I need to provide.

Comment: The user who restored the database should be the owner of the database; are you saying that they *aren't* the owner after restoring the DB?

Comment: The user being required to run the process is not present in the users list for the restored database.  I do not know how to tell if they are the owner or not, as they do not show up in the users list for that database at all.

Comment: The owner maps to the `dbo` user. That there's no `USER` with the same name as a `LOGIN` doesn't mean that that `LOGIN` *doesn't* have a mapped `USER`; there is no requirement the 2 have the same name. Have you actually tried access the database with the `LOGIN` after said `LOGIN` performed a `RESTORE`.

Comment: I had thought that was what was happening when the next script block (the one erroring out) ran against the database immediately after the reload.  If I am incorrect in this, please tell me the proper way to test that.

Comment: I think you should, at this point, be posting the code you're using and telling us the what `LOGIN` these are running under.

Comment: Well, you probably can't add yourself. I'm not a rights expert, but you could create a stored procedure with sysadmin as owner that is executed as owner and which just executes the second script you posted. This way, there should be no leaking of rights. Your domain user can be added so it can execute the procedure of course

Comment: Verify the vendor is not using partial containment.  Make sure the dbowner is not blank after it's restored.  Does the second step run as the same user?  If not, does it have ALTER ANY USER and a perm to change the role in the db?  There's no weird deny permission set someplace like in the public role?  (Note: if the job is run as sa, no permission checks are done.  If run as the db owner, no db permission checks are done.  If run as a member of db_owner, permission checks are done - deny applies.)  Running a job as non-sa always is a headache for me.

Comment: Something like this after the restore in the procedure doing the restore would set the dbowner.  It will have full db access without being added as a user.  
use SPDB; exec sp_changedbowner 'domain\svc.an'

Comment: The database properties tabs will show the owner and the containment type.  The owner is not a user but can be added as a user.

Comment: If the vendor has the user in the database, that would be something to note.  it most likely won't have the correct SID.  The name might look right, but it will never map until fixed.